# In OpenLayers can I replace a kml's URL for OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP with the actual text of the kml?

Tags: openlayers-2

I had an OpenLayers map that reads in and displayed a kml like this:

```
var vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.KML({extractAttributes: true});

    var vector_protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: 'http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/thomlines.kml',
        format: vector_format
    });

    var vector_strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()];
        vector_Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('More Advanced Vector Layer',{
            protocol: vector_protocol,
            strategies: vector_strategies
        });
```

I am producing the with a perl file and have the kml as a variable. Can I replace the url (`{
            url: 'http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s0825955/thomlines.kml',`) with the actual kml text as stored in my scalar variable `$newkml` ? and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used scalar before, but if you can store the kml text as a javascript string, then you can just use an `OpenLayers.Format.KML` object to read geometries from the kml text.

Some thing like this:

```
var kml_string = "..."; // you kml text stored as a javascript string
var kmlParser = new OpenLayers.Format.KML(); // Initialize with options if necessary
var feature_list = kmlParser.read(kml_string);
```

The `feature_list` is the vector features from kml text.

Comment: have you had anyproblems with the first line of KML having characters that javascript doesn't like?

one of these: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

Do I need to add some backslackes?

Comment: yes, backslash is one option. Another option is to use single quotation to quote you whole kml text.

Comment: have you had any issues with feature list being undefined when you call its methods?

Comment: maybe i need to incorporate my vector_stretegies?
When I was getting the kml by url i used:
  `var vector_strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()];`

Comment: I've just checked your kml file, and the file contains both single and double quotes inside. So the single quotes option will not work. I think there should be some way that you can assign your scalar variable ($newkml) to a javascript variable, maybe that's a better option.

Comment: yeah I think I've fixed the quotes and tried it as a javascript variable. at the moment its not giving me any errors but doesn't display anything. wierd.