# OpenLayers load KML 64 string data URI

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, .net, openlayers-2

I am trying to load a KML file to Google Maps using OpenLayers 2, below is the code:

```
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
          "OpenLayers WMS",
          "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
          { layers: 'basic' }
      );

var sundials = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
    projection: this.application.map.map.displayProjection,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        //url: "http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/kml/lines.kml",
        //url: this.application.CommonLocation + "scripts/Testing.kml",
        //url: 'data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;base64,' + this.tmpKml,
        url: 'data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;base64,' + "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",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
            extractStyles: true,
            extractAttributes: true
        })
    })
});
```

However, Chrome throw the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIi…AgICA8L1BsYWNlbWFyaz4NCiAgICA8L0ZvbGRlcj4NCiAgPC9Eb2N1bWVudD4NCjwva21sPg==. Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I have followed the step in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409600/error-request-header-field-content-type-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow

But still unable to solve it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoded string is a KML document. You already have the features in your encoded string, right?

You can use the native Javascript `atob()` function to decode the string. Try it on the Javascript console.

Afterwards, use `OpenLayers.Format.KML` to parse the string to create a new vector layer.

There is already a SO question related with [KML parsing in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65291/in-openlayers-can-i-replace-a-kmls-url-for-openlayers-protocol-http-with-the-ac).

Comment: Thx jgorcha. I have followed your advice and managed to produce the xml string of the kml. I hae followed the link that you sent but stil unabel to show the layer on the map. I have posted this in a new question below:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163614/show-kml-from-variable-instead-of-url